# Conky harmattan text is mis-aligned

Tags: 14.04, unity, conky

I am using [Conky Harmattan](https://github.com/zagortenay333/Harmattan) v1.9x and while I am able to set it up to display all the information, as you will see form the screen shot below the text in each section (God-mode) is aligned slightly to high and is going above the section divider lines. I have included my conky settings file below as well. Don't really know to much about conky but followed the instruction at the Harmattan site. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity. I have tried a few different Harmattan themes and this happens on them all.

What do I need to look at to align text properly?

[image]

```
#====================================
#   Conky Settings
#====================================
background yes
update_interval 1
double_buffer yes
no_buffers yes
imlib_cache_size 10

draw_shades no
draw_outline no
draw_borders no
draw_graph_borders no
default_graph_size 26 80
show_graph_scale no
show_graph_range no


#====================================
#   Window Specifications
#====================================
gap_x 100
gap_y 70
minimum_size 268 620
maximum_width 268
own_window yes
own_window_type normal  # other options are: override/dock/desktop/panel
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorate,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager,below
border_inner_margin 0
border_outer_margin 0
#alignment middle_middle
#own_window_argb_visual yes
#own_window_argb_value 0


#====================================
#   Text Settings
#====================================
use_xft yes
xftalpha 0
xftfont Droid Sans:size=8
text_buffer_size 256
override_utf8_locale yes

short_units yes
short_units yes
pad_percents 2
top_name_width 7


#====================================
#   Color Scheme
#====================================
default_color FFFFFF
color1 FFFFFF
color2 FFFFFF
color3 FFFFFF
color4 FFFFFF
color5 DCDCDC
color6 FFFFFF
color7 FFFFFF
color8 FFFFFF


#====================================
#   API Key
#====================================
template6 ""


#====================================
#   City ID
#====================================
template7 ""


#====================================
#   Temp Unit (default, metric, imperial)
#====================================
template8 metric


#====================================
#   Locale (e.g. "es_ES.UTF-8")
#   Leave empty for default
#   Leave the quotes
#====================================
template9 ""


###################################################
###################################################


TEXT
#----------------------------------------
#   CURL
#----------------------------------------
\
\
${execi 300 l=${template9}; l=${l%%_*}; curl -s "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?APPID=${template6}&id=${template7}&cnt=5&units=${template8}&lang=$l" -o ~/.cache/forecast.json}\
${execi 300 l=${template9}; l=${l%%_*}; curl -s "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=${template6}&id=${template7}&cnt=5&units=${template8}&lang=$l" -o ~/.cache/weather.json}\
\
\
#----------------------------------------
#   Misc Images
#----------------------------------------
\
\
${image ~/.harmattan-assets/misc/Transparent/God-Mode/separator-v.png -p 95,185 -s 1x76}\
${image ~/.harmattan-assets/misc/Transparent/God-Mode/separator-v.png -p 172,185 -s 1x76}\
${image ~/.harmattan-assets/misc/Transparent/God-Mode/separator-h.png -p 33,90 -s 202x1}\
${image ~/.harmattan-assets/misc/Transparent/God-Mode/separator-h.png -p 33,176 -s 202x1}\
${image ~/.harmattan-assets/misc/Transparent/God-Mode/separator-h.png -p 33,269 -s 202x1}\
${image ~/.harmattan-assets/misc/Transparent/God-Mode/separator-h.png -p 33,369 -s 202x1}\
${image ~/.harmattan-assets/misc/Transparent/God-Mode/separator-h.png -p 33,474 -s 202x1}\
\
\
#----------------------------------------
#   Day names
#----------------------------------------
\
\
${color3}${voffset 172}${alignc 77}${execi 300 LANG=${template9} LC_TIME=${template9} date +%^a}${color}
${color3}${voffset -13}${alignc}${execi 300 LANG=${template9} LC_TIME=${template9} date -d +1day +%^a}${color}
${color3}${voffset -13}${alignc -77}${execi 300 LANG=${template9} LC_TIME=${template9} date -d +2day +%^a}${color}
\
\
#----------------------------------------
#   Temperatures
#----------------------------------------
\
\
${color2}${voffset 51}${alignc 77}${execi 300 jq -r .list[0].temp.min ~/.cache/forecast.json | awk '{print int($1+0.5)}' # round num}°/${execi 300 jq -r .list[0].temp.max ~/.cache/forecast.json | awk '{print int($1+0.5)}' # round num}°${color}
${color2}${voffset -13}${alignc}${execi 300 jq -r .list[1].temp.min ~/.cache/forecast.json | awk '{print int($1+0.5)}' # round num}°/${execi 300 jq -r .list[1].temp.max ~/.cache/forecast.json | awk '{print int($1+0.5)}' # round num}°${color}
${color2}${voffset -13}${alignc -77}${execi 300 jq -r .list[2].temp.min ~/.cache/forecast.json | awk '{print int($1+0.5)}' # round num}°/${execi 300 jq -r .list[2].temp.max ~/.cache/forecast.json | awk '{print int($1+0.5)}' # round num}°${color}
\
\
#----------------------------------------
#   Conditions
#----------------------------------------
\
\
${goto 36}${voffset -172}${font Droid Sans :size=36}${color1}${execi 300 jq -r .main.temp ~/.cache/weather.json | awk '{print int($1+0.5)}' # round num}°${font}${color}
${goto 46}${voffset 14}${font Droid Sans :size=12}${color1}${execi 300 jq -r .weather[0].description ~/.cache/weather.json | sed 's|\<.|\U&|g'}${font}${color}
${color1}${alignr 62}${voffset -73}${execi 300 jq -r .main.pressure ~/.cache/weather.json | awk '{print int($1+0.5)}' # round num} hPa
${color1}${alignr 62}${voffset 7}${execi 300 jq -r .main.humidity ~/.cache/weather.json | awk '{print int($1+0.5)}' # round num} %${color}
${color1}${alignr 62}${voffset 7}${execi 300 jq -r .wind.speed ~/.cache/weather.json | awk '{print int($1+0.5)}' # round num}${if_match "$template8" == "metric"} m/s${else}${if_match "$template8" == "default"} m/s${else}${if_match "$template8" == "imperial"} mi/h${endif}${endif}${endif}${color}
\
\
#----------------------------------------
#   Clock and Date
#----------------------------------------
\
\
${voffset -117}${font Droid Sans Mono :size=22}${alignc}${color2}${time %H:%M}${font}${color}
${voffset 4}${font Droid Sans :size=10}${alignc}${color6}${execi 300 LANG=${template9} LC_TIME=${template9} date +"%A, %B %-d"}${font}${color}
\
\
#----------------------------------------
#   Cpu, memory, uptime, and load graph
#----------------------------------------
\
\
${voffset 294}${goto 40}${color2}Cpu:${color}
${voffset 4}${goto 40}${color2}Mem:${color}
${voffset 4}${goto 40}${color2}Uptime:${color}
${voffset -47}${alignr 39}${color2}${cpu cpu0}%${color}
${voffset 4}${alignr 39}${color2}${memperc}%${color}
${voffset 4}${alignr 39}${color2}${uptime_short}${color}
${voffset -47}${alignc}${color2}${cpubar 5,36}${color}
${voffset 4}${alignc}${color2}${membar 5,36}${color}
${voffset 29}${goto 40}${loadgraph 26,190 FFFFFF FFFFFF -l}
\
\
#----------------------------------------
#   Processes
#----------------------------------------
\
\
${voffset 26}${goto 40}${color2}${top_mem name 1}${color}
${voffset 4}${goto 40}${color2}${top_mem name 2}${color}
${voffset 4}${goto 40}${color2}${top_mem name 3}${color}
${voffset 4}${goto 40}${color2}${top_mem name 4}${color}
${voffset 4}${goto 40}${color2}${top_mem name 5}${color}
${voffset -81}${alignc}${color5}${top_mem mem 1}%${color}
${voffset 4}${alignc}${color5}${top_mem mem 2}%${color}
${voffset 4}${alignc}${color5}${top_mem mem 3}%${color}
${voffset 4}${alignc}${color5}${top_mem mem 4}%${color}
${voffset 4}${alignc}${color5}${top_mem mem 5}%${color}
${voffset -81}${alignr 39}${color6}${top_mem mem_res 1}${color}
${voffset 4}${alignr 39}${color6}${top_mem mem_res 2}${color}
${voffset 4}${alignr 39}${color6}${top_mem mem_res 3}${color}
${voffset 4}${alignr 39}${color6}${top_mem mem_res 4}${color}
${voffset 4}${alignr 39}${color6}${top_mem mem_res 5}${color}
${voffset -104}${goto 40}${color1}Proc${color}
${voffset -13}${alignc}${color1}Mem%${color}
${voffset -13}${alignr 39}${color1}Mem${color}
\
\
#----------------------------------------
#   Network
#----------------------------------------
\
\
${if_existing /proc/net/route ppp0}
${voffset -227}${goto 40}${color5}Up: ${color2}${upspeed ppp0}${color5}${goto 150}Down: ${color2}${downspeed ppp0}
${voffset 10}${goto 40}${upspeedgraph ppp0 26,80 FFFFFF FFFFFF}${goto 150}${downspeedgraph ppp0 26,80 FFFFFF FFFFFF}
${voffset 9}${goto 40}${color5}Sent: ${color2}${totalup ppp0}${color5}${goto 150}Received: ${color2}${totaldown ppp0}
${else}
${if_existing /proc/net/route ppp1}
${voffset -240}${goto 40}${color5}Up: ${color2}${upspeed ppp1}${color5}${goto 150}Down: ${color2}${downspeed ppp1}
${voffset 10}${goto 40}${upspeedgraph ppp1 26,80 FFFFFF FFFFFF}${goto 150}${downspeedgraph ppp1 26,80 FFFFFF FFFFFF}
${voffset 9}${goto 40}${color5}Sent: ${color2}${totalup ppp1}${color5}${goto 150}Received: ${color2}${totaldown ppp1}
${else}
${if_existing /proc/net/route wlp2s1}
${voffset -253}${goto 40}${color5}Up: ${color2}${upspeed wlp2s1}${color5}${goto 150}Down: ${color2}${downspeed wlp2s1}
${voffset 10}${goto 40}${upspeedgraph wlp2s1 26,80 FFFFFF FFFFFF}${goto 150}${downspeedgraph wlp2s1 26,80 FFFFFF FFFFFF}
${voffset 9}${goto 40}${color5}Sent: ${color2}${totalup wlp2s1}${color5}${goto 150}Received: ${color2}${totaldown wlp2s1}
${else}
${if_existing /proc/net/route wlp2s0}
${voffset -266}${goto 40}${color5}Up: ${color2}${upspeed wlp2s0}${color5}${goto 150}Down: ${color2}${downspeed wlp2s0}
${voffset 10}${goto 40}${upspeedgraph wlp2s0 26,80 FFFFFF FFFFFF}${goto 150}${downspeedgraph wlp2s0 26,80 FFFFFF FFFFFF}
${voffset 9}${goto 40}${color5}Sent: ${color2}${totalup wlp2s0}${color5}${goto 150}Received: ${color2}${totaldown wlp2s0}
${else}
${if_existing /proc/net/route wlan0}
${voffset -279}${goto 40}${color5}Up: ${color2}${upspeed wlan0}${color5}${goto 150}Down: ${color2}${downspeed wlan0}
${voffset 8}${goto 40}${upspeedgraph wlan0 26,80 FFFFFF FFFFFF}${goto 150}${downspeedgraph wlan0 26,80 FFFFFF FFFFFF}
${voffset 9}${goto 40}${color5}Sent: ${color2}${totalup wlan0}${color5}${goto 150}Received: ${color2}${totaldown wlan0}
${else}
${if_existing /proc/net/route wlan1}
${voffset -292}${goto 40}${color5}Up: ${color2}${upspeed wlan1}${color5}${goto 150}Down: ${color2}${downspeed wlan1}
${voffset 10}${goto 40}${upspeedgraph wlan1 26,80 FFFFFF FFFFFF}${goto 150}${downspeedgraph wlan1 26,80 FFFFFF FFFFFF}
${voffset 9}${goto 40}${color5}Sent: ${color2}${totalup wlan1}${color5}${goto 150}Received: ${color2}${totaldown wlan1}
${else}
${if_existing /proc/net/route eth1}
${voffset -305}${goto 40}${color5}Up: ${color2}${upspeed eth1}${color5}${goto 150}Down: ${color2}${downspeed eth1}
${voffset 10}${goto 40}${upspeedgraph eth1 26,80 FFFFFF FFFFFF}${goto 150}${downspeedgraph eth1 26,80 FFFFFF FFFFFF}
${voffset 9}${goto 40}${color5}Sent: ${color2}${totalup eth1}${color5}${goto 150}Received: ${color2}${totaldown eth1}
${else}
${if_existing /proc/net/route eth0}
${voffset -318}${goto 40}${color5}Up: ${color2}${upspeed eth0}${color5}${goto 150}Down: ${color2}${downspeed eth0}
${voffset 10}${goto 40}${upspeedgraph eth0 26,80 FFFFFF FFFFFF}${goto 150}${downspeedgraph eth0 26,80 FFFFFF FFFFFF}
${voffset 9}${goto 40}${color5}Sent: ${color2}${totalup eth0}${color5}${goto 150}Received: ${color2}${totaldown eth0}
${else}
${if_existing /proc/net/route enp0s0}
${voffset -331}${goto 40}${color5}Up: ${color2}${upspeed enp0s0}${color5}${goto 150}Down: ${color2}${downspeed enp0s0}
${voffset 10}${goto 40}${upspeedgraph enp0s0 26,80 FFFFFF FFFFFF}${goto 150}${downspeedgraph enp0s0 26,80 FFFFFF FFFFFF}
${voffset 9}${goto 40}${color5}Sent: ${color2}${totalup enp0s0}${color5}${goto 150}Received: ${color2}${totaldown enp0s0}
${else}
${if_existing /proc/net/route enp0s1}
${voffset -344}${goto 40}${color5}Up: ${color2}${upspeed enp0s1}${color5}${goto 150}Down: ${color2}${downspeed enp0s1}
${voffset 10}${goto 40}${upspeedgraph enp0s1 26,80 FFFFFF FFFFFF}${goto 150}${downspeedgraph enp0s1 26,80 FFFFFF FFFFFF}
${voffset 9}${goto 40}${color5}Sent: ${color2}${totalup enp0s1}${color5}${goto 150}Received: ${color2}${totaldown enp0s1}
${else}
${voffset -311}${goto 40}${color5}Network disconnected${color}
${image ~/.harmattan-assets/misc/Transparent/God-Mode/offline.png -p 44,284 -s 16x16}
${endif}${endif}${endif}${endif}${endif}${endif}${endif}${endif}${endif}${endif}
\
\
#----------------------------------------
#   Weather icons
#----------------------------------------
\
\
${image ~/.harmattan-assets/misc/Transparent/God-Mode/pressure.png -p 210,95 -s 16x16}\
${image ~/.harmattan-assets/misc/Transparent/God-Mode/humidity.png -p 210,115 -s 16x16}\
${image ~/.harmattan-assets/misc/Transparent/God-Mode/wind-2.png -p 210,136 -s 16x16}\
${execi 300 cp -f ~/.harmattan-assets/icons/#fff__32/$(jq .list[0].weather[0].id ~/.cache/forecast.json).png ~/.cache/weather-1.png}${image ~/.cache/weather-1.png -p 41,207 -s 32x32}\
${execi 300 cp -f ~/.harmattan-assets/icons/#fff__32/$(jq .list[1].weather[0].id ~/.cache/forecast.json).png ~/.cache/weather-2.png}${image ~/.cache/weather-2.png -p 119,207 -s 32x32}\
${execi 300 cp -f ~/.harmattan-assets/icons/#fff__32/$(jq .list[2].weather[0].id ~/.cache/forecast.json).png ~/.cache/weather-3.png}${image ~/.cache/weather-3.png -p 195,207 -s 32x32}${font}${voffset -120}\
```

Comment: Try changing the voffset values, voffset is vertical offset. You might get the desired result. If you change values you will see that all text beneath the change is affected.

Comment: @jeroen Changing the first voffset did the trick. Feel free to write that up as a answer if you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the placement of the text vertically, change the voffset value. Voffset means vertical offset. All textpositions beneath the line in wich the voffset value is changed will be affected.